# Pandas run Converting program to contents of a folder

Tags: python, pandas, automation, jupyter-notebook, pyautogui

I've created a program so that I can split the column into 2 columns by specifying the location of the file but I would like to do this for an entire folder so that the process can be a bit faster.

Here is the code for my program:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

// reading csv file from url
filepath = "C:/Users/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/filename.csv"
file_encoding = 'cp1252' 
data = pd.read_csv(filepath , header=None , encoding=file_encoding)

data.columns =['Last Name', 'First Name']

// new data frame with split value columns
new = data["Name"].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True)

// making separate first name column from new data frame
data["Last Name"]= new[0]

// making separate last name column from new data frame
data["First Name"]= new[1]

// new data frame with split value columns 
new = data["SName"].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True)

// making separate first name column from new data frame
data["S Last Name"]= new[0]

// making separate last name column from new data frame
data["S First Name"]= new[1]

// Saving File name as its path
filename = os.path.basename(filepath) + ".xlsx"
data.to_excel(filename, index=False)

data
```

I created an automated text to column program so that I don't have to manually do for hundreds of data entries. But I have done it for a specified file. I would like to take this code a bit further by allowing it to take a folder of .csv and do the conversions.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your code in a function:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def splitter(folder_path):

    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
        
            # reading csv file from url
            filepath = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
            file_encoding = 'cp1252' 
            data = pd.read_csv(filepath , header=None , encoding=file_encoding)

            data.columns =['Last Name', 'First Name']

            # new data frame with split value columns
            new = data["Name"].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True)

            # making separate first name column from new data frame
            data["Last Name"]= new[0]

            # making separate last name column from new data frame
            data["First Name"]= new[1]

            # new data frame with split value columns 
            new = data["SName"].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True)

            # making separate first name column from new data frame
            data["S Last Name"]= new[0]

            # making separate last name column from new data frame
            data["S First Name"]= new[1]

            # Saving File name as its path
            filename = os.path.basename(filepath) + ".xlsx"
            data.to_excel(filename, index=False)
            
            print(file, " is done.")


# Example
fpath = "C:/Users/username/folder1/folder2/folder3"
splitter(fpath)
```

Comment: Thank you this works, Can you help with this also; I would like to to have an if else for `data.columns` so that I would avoid the tokenizing error. Some of my data has 2 and 3 columns, So if fields = 2 then data.columns... else if field = 2 then data.columns ... Or maybe I can automatically add more columns in addition to the already specified column names but how can I achieve these things? Thanks for your help thus far

Comment: @Kenny It would be better for you to start a new question for this. Also make sure to provide an example csv file; all the columns and a few example rows are good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) library.

```py
from glob import glob

files = glob('C:/Users/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/*')

for file in files:
    # ... your function/code
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'm sure this would work since its concept is the same as @a11 's answer

Comment: @Kenny this is different and a good alternative because it uses glob instead of os.

Comment: @a11 okay will attempt after, thanks